# how to make mod_rewrite to redirect from subdomains to querystring?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to make mod rewrite as the following example :

from google.com.mydomain.com to mydomain.com/index.php?domain=google.com

I use like

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !domain=
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.mydomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?domain=%1 [L,QSA]
```

but this redirect google.mydomain.com to mydomain.com/index.php?domain=google

I want rule to redirect google.com not google

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is due to the incorrect regex. Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !domain=
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+?)\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?domain=%1 [L,QSA]
```

In your rule you're using `[^\.]+` which matched until a dot is found therefore it is matching `google` instead of `google.com`.