# Make Subdomain Post Request

Tags: php, forms, .htaccess, subdomain, action

How would I make it so that a subdomain of a website acts as a get/post action and request. For example, all subdomains would work as a form action and visiting subdomain.mywebsite.com would be the same as visiting mywebsite.com/?id=subdomain.

I've seen similar things like this done before but have never seen anything on how this can be done.

Thank you in advance for any help or information.

Comment: Here [how-to-make-mod-rewrite-to-redirect-from-subdomains-to-querystring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20681985/how-to-make-mod-rewrite-to-redirect-from-subdomains-to-querystring)

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www).+)\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://domain.com/?id=%1 [L,R]
```